# How to make a Calculator using extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, calculator

I'm trying to make a tabbed app to the store I work. It's to count the money and see if it's right.

In the first tab is the aplication, and in the second one, I wanna put a calculator (like the Android's one). Then, I'm using a Tabbed Activity so my Java classes have `extends Fragment`.

I'm trying to watch some YouTube videos, but every one uses `extends AppCompatActivity`, so I made the same code, but I think this one doesn't work like Fragments. My app isn't working when I try to run it.

What can I do to make this work? What can I change?

I already put the methods in "onClick" on Layout's Button.

```
package com.example.ayrton.fecharcaixa;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TabCalc extends Fragment{

    TextView screen;
    String display = "";
    String currentOperator = "";

    public TabCalc(){

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_calculadora, container, false);
        screen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtScreen);
        screen.setText("");
        return view;
    }
    public void updateScreen(){
        screen.setText(display);
    }

    public void onClickNumber (View v){
        Button b = (Button) v;
        display += b.getText();
        updateScreen();
    }

    public void onClickOperator(View v){
        Button b = (Button)v;
        display += b.getText();
        currentOperator = b.getText().toString();
        updateScreen();
    }

    public void clear(){
        display = "";
        currentOperator = "";
        updateScreen();
    }

    public void onClickPonto(View v){
        Button b = (Button)v;
        display += b.getText();
        updateScreen();
    }

    public void onClickClear(View v){
        clear();
        updateScreen();
    }

    public void onClickEqual(View v){
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ayrton.fecharcaixa, PID: 12074
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClickNumber(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'bt7'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: You should set the click listener in the Java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your onClickNumber(View) in the Tabbed Activity where the fragment is included.

The other solution is to define the onclicklistener of the button in the fragment class code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_calculadora, container, false);
        screen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtScreen);
        screen.setText("");

        Button yourButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
        yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  onClickNumber(v);
             }
        });
        return view;
}
```